# On click get <a> <href> value to add to the URL path

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="slist selected" id="ele1"><a href="#!id1">Element 1</a></li>
  <li class="slist" id="ele2"><a href="#!id2">Element 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

When i clicked slist li, it should get id from  tag and add to this existing "http://www.example.com/test1.html"

Please let me know..how to do this?
http://www.example.com/test1.html#!id1

Comment: From where `http://www.example.com/test1.html` came from?

Comment: If you just need to append `#` hash value, it is the default behavior of `<a>`, and will automatically happen on click.

Comment: HI Shaunak... on click have to add #!id1.. Also.. we are using ajax call to filter and display div container based on id clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

This will work if you have id of li element similar to href

```
$(".slist").click( function(){
  var id = $(this).prop("id");
  $("a[href*='"+id+"' ]").prop("href", "http://www.example.com/test1.html#!"+id);
}
);
```

or

This will work when you just directly want to go and modify the child a element of the li ..I suggest to go with this solution as it not going to cause any problem

```
$(".slist").click( function(){
  var id = $(this).prop("id");
  var a = $( "#" + id + ">a");
  a.prop("href", "http://www.example.com/test1.html#!"+id);
  alert(a.prop("href"));
}
);
```

[Working Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71fzvcaL/)

Comment: Hi Pranay.. thanks for your code.. But, url is not changing as expected when clicked.

Comment: @venkatesha - check working code on js fiddle ..i updated code and its working please do check and accept answer if it works for you

Comment: sorry.. not sure whether question is wrong.. http://www.example.com/test1.html page will load with <ul><li> codes given on top. When i click <li> with id "ele1", it have to get id value of <a>tag and change url to http://www.example.com/test1.html#!id1

Comment: As per your solution.. i don't want any reload or redirection option. If u need or have time to help me out.. please let me know.. i will share related files to your mail. Share me your mail address.. Thanks

Comment: @venkatesha - not getting you but there is no reload or redirecion done when changing url..as you given i updated url value in my answer

Comment: Bro.. you are getting id.. but url on browser window not changing with with id.. Once i clicked <li> element.. browser window url have to change like http://www.example.com/test1.html#!id1. But, still i can see only http://www.example.com/test1.html

Comment: @venkatesha - i m not getting you at all..if href is changed than alert box will show you correct href as per code...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var attr = $(this).prop('id');
var currentUrl = document.location;

document.location.assign(currentUrl + attr);

)}
```